# jQuery click event on td row not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a simple bit of jQuery which displays the row below the current one if selected.

What I want if for all the `<td>` elements but one to fire this method.

Works on whole `<tr>` row

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#report > tbody > tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("#report tr").fadeToggle(600);
        });
    });
```

want to do something like (doesn't work)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#report > tbody > tr.odd > td.selected").click(function(){
            $(this).next("#report tr").fadeToggle(600);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#report tr:first-child").show();

    $("#report > tbody > tr.odd > td.selected").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").fadeToggle(600);
    });
});
```

Since you're clicking a td, need to go up to the row before trying to get the next row.  Also this selector should work the same in most cases: `#report td.selected`.  Since you can't escape being inside the `#report` with a sibling, `#report tr` can also be just `tr` in your `next()`.

Answer (score 4):

In your non-working code, `$(this)` is a `<td>` element.

Therefore, `$(this).next("#report tr")` doesn't match anything.  (Because the `<td>` element has no  `<tr>` elements as siblings)

You need to change it to `$(this).closest('tr').next("#report tr")` to find the "uncle" element.  You could also call `.parent()` instead of `.closest('tr')`, but calling `.closest` will keep working even if you bind the `click` handler to a child of the `<td>`.